# Block archive.today From Crawling My Site?

Tags: firewall, iptables, internet-filter

My website is being scraped by archive.today. This site is similar to the reputable archive.org, but archive.today does not obey robots.txt, spoofs a generic user-agent and tried to hide its IPs. The site then proceeds to regurgitate your content and index it is search engines.

Comment: On [webmasters.se]: [Deny access to Archive.is](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/88257/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block the crawler by blocking the following IP ranges:

```
78.46.174.128/27 & 108.61.0.0/16 & 5.101.96.0/21
```

Once you block these, trying to index a page with archive.today should result in an endless loop on their site.

You can do it in iptables like:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 78.46.174.128/27 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 108.61.0.0/16 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 5.101.96.0/21 -j DROP
```

And I imagine Apache and ngix have a way to do something similar.

archive.today defeated:

[image]

If you do not see this, they have probably got some new IPs.